How to detect if a device is an iPad, Tablet or phone in Compose Multiplatform for Android and iOS
I'm working on a Compose Multiplatform project, and I need to adjust the UI based on whether the user is using a tablet, iPad, or phone. I'm looking for a detailed solution that includes platform-specific checks for both Android and iOS within the Compose Multiplatform framework.

To detect if a device is a tablet, iPad, or phone in Compose Multiplatform for Android and iOS, you can utilize platform-specific APIs to determine the device type. Here’s how you can achieve this:
Add expect method in the shared UI module(CommonMain) code,
// returns true if a device is tablet or iPad
@Composable
expect fun isTabletOrIPad(): Boolean

Add implementations for iOS and Android code,
iOS spefici code below:
// platform.ios.kt
@Composable
actual fun isTabletOrIPad(): Boolean {
    return UIDevice.currentDevice.userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad
}

Android specific code here:
// platform.android.kt
@Composable
actual fun isTabletOrIPad(): Boolean {
    val configuration = LocalConfiguration.current
    return if (configuration.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        configuration.screenWidthDp > 840
    } else {
        configuration.screenWidthDp > 600
    }
}

